# Why do some people refer to jars as "glass jars"? Aren't all jars made of glass?

Tags: word-choice

A jar is defined as "a glass container with a lid" (MacMillan). At one time, people differentiated between glass and earthenware jars but to my mind, there are only glass jars these days. Is there a need to refer to a jar as a "glass jar"? Isn't it sufficient to simply call it a jar?

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167993/difference-between-mug-jug-jar-etc

Comment: @Pepper Have you tried looking for jars that are made out of things other than glass?

Comment: [Fajance Jar](http://i.ebayimg.com/03/!B+i7sU!CWk~$(KGrHqEOKm4EzyjVlVQZBM+-,zosFg~~_12.JPG)

Comment: Check a few other on line dictionaries, few are quite as restrictive in the description as MacMillan are (including the need for a wide top and a lid).

Comment: Funny, when I hear the word _jar_, devoid of context, I think immediately of earthenware. Even if you say ‘a jar of marmalade’, my initial thought is an earthenwear jar of marmalade, proper rustic-style. The only context I can think of where _jar_ on its own makes me think of glass is in a spooky laboratory (or [Snape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severus_snape)’s office) where you’ve got all kinds of creepy, dismembered things floating in jars along the walls. And even there, I’d say _glass jars_ more naturally.

Comment: Check out the images for [cookie jar](https://www.google.com/search?q=cookie+jar&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Gy7FU5u8N7TfsATkxoKYBg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1366&bih=643). Most are non-glass.

Comment: 'A jar is defined as "a glass container with a lid" ' sounds a done deal. But I could equally well say 'A jar is defined as "a wide-mouthed, cylindrical container made of glass or pottery, especially one used for storing food' (Google)".

Comment: Actually, a good many jars are now made of plastic, but people have tended to refer to glass jars as a generic term prior to advent of plastic as a common material for jars. Most likely the usage goes back to the advent of glass jars when people needed to differentiate from the older (ancient) types of ceramic jars. And from there it likely became habitual.

Comment: Nice, @GMB. Now try to find a dictionary that's good enough to include 'plastic':-) (And to think I've just written 'Are you saying your judgement is better than Dictionary X's?' on another thread!)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I actually saw and appreciated your dictionary comment. Just because we may not bow down before a dictioanry doesn't mean they aren't worth consulting, and even citing--especially when they agree with us.

Comment: @GMB Are you a politician?

Comment: Nope, @ Edwin Ashworth.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a couple of good reasons to say "glass jar":

- As you note, not all jars are made of glass. Aside from the earlier use of the word to refer to earthenware vessels and the like, many things that were once commonly made of glass are now increasingly constructed from plastic, including clear, cylindrical, wide-mouthed containers of the sort we've always been comfortable referring to as "jars." Is a jar of peanut butter any less of a jar of peanut butter if the vessel is made of plastic instead of glass?
- [Redundant modifiers](http://www.enhancemyvocabulary.com/redundant-words.html), though often disparaged, can be useful ways of emphasizing a particular quality or of evoking a certain image. I might write of "a shelf full of glass jars catching the light from the window" intending to focus the reader's mind on the peculiar quality of the light that plays off of a curved glass surface. In such a case, it is the glass that is of primary importance, and the shape of the vessel (jar, bottle, flask, something else) that is secondary. In a way, then, *jar* serves as a modifier for *glass*, not the other way around.